# why a conversion function declaration does not require at least one defining-type-specifier

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

> Except in a declaration of a constructor, destructor, or conversion function, at least one defining-type-specifier that is not a cv-qualifier shall appear in a complete **type-specifier-seq** or a complete **decl-specifier-seq**.

Constructor is an exception because constructor can be declared like `constructor(){}`, No defining-type-specifier in this declaration, similarly for destructor.

For `conversion function`, I can't have a idea that a conversion function does not need a type-specifier when I think in the above quote, `defining-type-specifier` contains `type-specifier`, because the sentence **defining-type-specifier that is not a cv-qualifier** implies that, only **type-specifier** contains cv-qualifier, Hence I think a conversion function declaration shall  contain at least a **defining-type-specifier**(in less range, it's type-specifier that is a subset of defining-type-specifier), The grammar of a conversion function likes as the following, due to [[dcl.fct.def#general-1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#general-1):

> attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq(opt) declarator  virt-specifier-seq(opt) function-body

Thereof, its declarator will like as the following:

> operator conversion-type-id
>
> > conversion-type-id
> >
> > > **type-specifier-seq** conversion-declarator(opt)

However according to [[class.conv.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.fct#1), It says:

> A decl-specifier in the **decl-specifier-seq** of a conversion function (if any) shall be neither a **defining-type-specifier** nor static.

It means the `decl-specifier-seq(opt)` can't be a defining-type-specifier nor static.

But, in the type-specifier-seq of a conversion-type-id, It must be a defining-type-specifier.

```cpp
operator Type(){  // Type is a defining-type-specifier(more exactly,it's a type-specifier)
  return Type{};
}
```

and you wouldn't define a conversion functions like this:

```cpp
operator (){ // there's no defining-type-specifier in type-specifier-seq
  //...
}
```

[[dcl.fct#11]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#11)

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

This is a restriction for that the defining-type-specifier must appear in a function declaration, Due to

#### defining-type-specifier consists of:

> - type-specifier
> - class-specifier
> - enum-specifier

`class-specifier` or `enum-specifier` can't be used in a decl-specifier-seq of a function delcaration because of the last quote. only `type-specifier` is permitted.

So, as far as now, what the standard actually wants to say is that, use a *more range* wording for **type-specifier**, namely, **defining-type-specifier**, because you indeed can declare a variable likes `struct A{} variable;`, there's no **class-specifier** be contained in type-specifier, hence, as a general rule, the standard use the "wording" **defining-type-specifier** to cover such cases.

So, why conversion function is an exception in the first rule? If there're any misunderstandings in the above analysis, correct me.

### Questions:

1. why a conversion function is an exception in the first quote?
2. If a conversion function is an exception, why other functions are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree - the paragraph [[dcl.type]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#3) should instead say something like:

> Except in a declaration of a constructor, destructor, or conversion function, or in a *lambda-declarator*, a complete *decl-specifier-seq* shall contain at least one *defining-type-specifier* that is not a *cv-qualifier*. A complete *type-specifier-seq* shall contain at least one *type-specifier* that is not a *cv-qualifier*.

You're correct that:

- *defining-type-specifier* parses a wider set of input token sequences than *type-specifier*.
- *decl-type-specifier* parses an even wider set of input token sequences than *defining-type-specifier*.
- `const` and `volatile` are valid in parsing any of the three.
- The syntaxes including `class ClassName {`...`};` and `enum EnumName {`...`};` are valid in a *defining-type-specifier* or a *decl-type-specifier* but not in a *type-specifier*.

The [C++ grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram) uses *type-specifier-seq* and *decl-specifier-seq* in many places where the name of a type is expected (plus a few where they're not to name a type). The quoted paragraph [[dcl.type]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#3) requiring "at least one *defining-type-specifier* that is not a *cv-qualifier*" in these sequences is mainly saying that in all of those contexts, variations which don't name a type at all are not permitted: you can't say `auto v1 = new const;` or `static constexpr typedef f();`. Most individual uses have additional restrictions on what sorts of *type-specifier* can and cannot appear there, but those such rules are in addition to this basic one. In particular, many of them don't allow defining types within the specifier sequence. But since *decl-type-specifier* is used within *simple-declaration* as the ordinary way to define classes and enumerations, this rule is not the place for that restriction.

The reason for excluding constructors, destructors, and conversion functions is that although they might not have a *decl-type-specifier-seq* at all, they might in fact use a *decl-type-specifier* which does not contain any *defining-type-specifier*.  For example, in

```
class MyClass {
public:
  explicit MyClass(int);
};
```

the constructor declaration has a *decl-type-specifier* whose only specifier is the `explicit` keyword, which is not a *defining-type-specifier*.

(However, in looking through, I found another context where the rule should NOT apply: A lambda expression allows an optional *decl-specifier-seq* after its parameter list, where the only permitted specifiers are `mutable` and `constexpr`; neither is a *defining-type-specifier*.)

I'm guessing this paragraph version came along with or following a change in the grammar between C++14 and C++17. The initial *decl-specifier-seq* in a *simple-declaration* was changed from optional to required. A new grammar symbol *nodeclspec-function-declaration* was added to cover cases of friend declarations and template-related declarations which declare constructors, destructors, or conversion functions with no initial specifiers and without defining them. Other declarations of constructors, destructors, and conversion functions are actually covered by either *function-definition* or *member-declaration*, which still use an optional *decl-specifier-seq*, so the changes to *simple-declaration* didn't affect them.

For conversion functions, the text in [[class.conv.fct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.fct#1) saying

> A *decl-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a conversion function (if any) shall be neither a *defining-type-specifier* nor `static`.

forms the actual requirement: The [dcl.type] sentence excludes a conversion function's *decl-type-specifier-seq* from its usual requirement, so it doesn't say anything about what is and isn't legal. This [class.conv.fct] sentence gives the actual rule for this case.

A conversion function may be declared:

- by a *function-definition* (if it has a body, including `=default;` or `=delete;`)
- by a *member-declaration* (inside a class definition, if the declaration does not have a body)
- by a *simple-declaration* or *nodeclspec-function-declaration* (if in a friend declaration, explicit specialization, or explicit instantiation)

A *nodeclspec-function-declaration* allows no initial specifiers, but the other three symbols all have a rule in which a *decl-specifier-seq* (either required or optional) is followed by either a *declarator* or an *init-declarator-list*. As you noted, the *declarator* for a conversion function contains the `operator` keyword followed by a *type-specifier-seq*. The *declarator* must also contain `()` or `(void)` or equivalent so that it declares a function with no arguments.

With a few more assumptions, the general form of a conversion function declaration is either

> *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `operator` *type-specifier-seq conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> parameters-and-qualifiers virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>* `;`

or

> *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `operator` *type-specifier-seq conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> parameters-and-qualifiers virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> function-body*

So there's an optional *decl-specifier-seq* before the `operator` keyword and a required *type-specifier-seq* after it. It's the *decl-specifier-seq* which might not be present at all, and which must not contain a *defining-type-specifier* (because you don't put a type before the `operator` keyword) or `static` (because a conversion function must always be a non-static member). But the *decl-specifier-seq* may contain `constexpr`, `inline`, `virtual`, or `explicit`, or combinations of those.

The trouble you've noticed is that the wording of [dcl.type]/3 also means it technically doesn't apply to the *type-specifier-seq* in such a declaration which names the target type for the conversion. ([[dcl.pre]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#4) clears up many similar statements about grammar symbols in a declaration, but doesn't apply to this case since there's no intervening scope involved.) We could still infer that a *defining-type-specifier* is needed from phrases in the Standard like "the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*". But it would be better if the rule in [dcl.type]/3 applied to this *type-specifier-seq* like it does to most of them.

Comment: yes, the rules in [class.conv.fct] is used to restrict what kind specifer of the decl-specifier-seq which is  before `operator` can be, however within the type-specifier-seq which is after `operator`, It must indeed require a defining-type-specifier (a wider set of type-specifier, because the rule in function declaration restrict the specifier shall not define a new type), it's my confusion, why a conversion function does not require a defining-type-specifier, it conflict with the aforementioned.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! That does look like a mistake: I'm pretty sure it didn't mean to exclude the _type-specifier-seq_ of a _conversion-function-id_ which is used in a conversion function declaration, only its _decl-specifier-seq_. Lots of rules which apply to "thinly nested" grammar symbols but not to "deeply nested" grammar symbols are that way because of [\[dcl.pre\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#4), but not this one since there is no scope between _declarator_ and the _decl-specifier-seq_ in this case.

Comment: Glad to see you have understood what I mean, thanks. So, it maybe a defect in the standard?

Comment: Edited. Yes, I'd consider it a minor defect.

Answer (score 1):

A function declaration *must* have a *defining-type-specifier* simply means that a function declaration must have the form:

```
   Type  f();
// ^^^^ defining-type-specifier (in this case, a type-specifier)
// this must be an existing type
```

and can't be of the form:

```
f(); // error, no defining-type-specifier
```

The quoted rule from [dcl.fct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#11):

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

has nothing to do with *defining-type-specifiers* (despite the similar terminology). It simply means that you can't *define* a type in the declaration of a function.

```
struct A{} f(); // error, can't define a type in return
```

```
void f(struct A{}); // error, can't define a type in parameter
```

so this is not in conflict with the exceptions quoted at the beginning of your question.

Comment: If think this question in your way, then what difference between functions and conversion functions, A conversion function declaration must have a defining-type-specifier, `operator Type();` and can't be of the form `operator ();`, `operator struct A{}();`..., It simply means that you can't define a type in the declaration of a  **conversion function**. then why conversion function is an exception mentioned in the first rule?